# Given date and time, how do you get the Epoch time?

Tags: c++, epoch

I have

```
int year, month, day, hour, min, sec
```

How can I get the epoch time in C++?

I am having difficulty figuring it out using Boost, any examples or alternative ways to do it?

Comment: You said you tried boost. Did you try http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/date_time.html? It comes with examples http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/date_time/examples.html

Answer (score 4):

Fill in a struct tm with your values, then call [`std::mktime()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/mktime).

I'm assuming by "get the epoch time" you mean the number of seconds since the epoch, i.e. Unix time_t.

Comment: this post is completely unhelpful, how do you get epoch time from calling mktime()?

Answer (score 2):

You're making it too complicated.  Have a look at the [time functions in the standard libraries](http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/gettimeofday/).

Answer (score 1):

This [boost example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/date_time/examples.html#date_time.examples.seconds_since_epoch) should do what you ask for if I did understand your problem correctly.

Comment: excellent, works perfectly BUT you must download the CSV file with timezones: http://svn.kulitorum.com/RepSnapper/Libraries/Boost1.40/libs/date_time/data/date_time_zonespec.csv

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/time.h>

int main ()
{
  unsigned long int seconds = time(NULL);
  std::cout << seconds << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```